# Angular 4 http post request shows data in the url

Tags: ajax, angular, typescript, post, model-view-controller

I try to create a login control in typescript. When i try to send data it's shown in url like get method.

Here's typescript code;

```
AdminLogin(login: any) {
    let loginJson = JSON.stringify({ login });
    let headers = new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(this.linkAdminLogin, loginJson, options)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .catch(this._errorHandler);
}
```

And here's c# method

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Login(string login)
{
    UserJson user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserJson>(login);

    string pass = user.Password.ToMD5();

    var rb = entity.Users.Where(a => a.Active == true && a.Username == user.Username && a.Password == pass).FirstOrDefault();

    if (rb != null)
    {
        Session["CurrentUser"] = rb;

        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

When i go like this in the Chrome's network panel Login url is like http://localhost/AngularProject/Ajax/Home/Login?login=%7B%22Username%22:%22blahblah%22,%22Password%22:%22blahblah%22%7D

If i use HttpPost attribute it doesn't work. It gives an error like Http 404 Not found error for the method.

I just try to hide the data from url. I'm new in the Angular so i'm waiting for your answers.

Comment: Have you added routing on c# side or attribute route?

Comment: I have 2 different routings. One of them in the RouteConfig.cs and it's like routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Ajax",
                url: "Ajax/{controller}/{action}/{login}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Ajax", action = "Login", login = UrlParameter.Optional }
            ); And the other one is in the arearegistration.cs config and it's like context.MapRoute(
                "Ajax_default",
                "Ajax/{controller}/{action}/{login}",
                new { action = "Index", login = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: Can you try to add a class with two property with same name you passed in request url like userName and password and add into parameter of action mathod like Login(LoginClass login)

Comment: it gives null exception for login object

Comment: you have to give two parameters in that method Login(string username, string password)

Comment: what about ts side?

Comment: also try with post and change it to HttpPost

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191851/discussion-between-niraj-oza-and-thrashead).

Comment: it still sends parameter with name login. do i need to change anything in the ts side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try something like this.
Angular example:

```
AdminLogin$(request: RequestModel): Observable<responseModel | type> {
  const url = '<url to api>';

  return this.http.post<responseModel | type>(url, {request})
    .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
```

}

C# example:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Login([FromBody] RequestModel request)
{
  // your code
  return Ok();
}
```

Comment: You are welcome, angular 2+ and c# combo is not easy at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this line

```
   let loginJson = JSON.stringify({ login });
```

Comment: I send login object directly and it still shows parameters in the url with HttpGet attribute. If i do it with HttpPost attribute it gives 404 error. Nothing changed i mean.

Answer (score 0):

Set up proxy configuration like [here](https://medium.com/@spencerfeng/setup-a-proxy-for-api-calls-for-your-angular-cli-app-6566c02a8c4d).

Comment: i couldn't do it. i didn't understand where to change it from.